# How to use firebase rules

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to integrating **Firebase** to my **Angular** app. I read many tutorials from internet on this topic, most of these tutorials suggest that I define the following rules for my Firebase database (which means 
 allowing read & write permission):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But what I see by default as my database rules is the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried to add the rules that most tutorials suggested (the "rules ..." thing), errors occured: `'Error saving rules - Line 9: Unexpected '{'.` (I also tried to replace the original rules by the rules that the tutorials suggested, same error)

It seems that none of the tutorials said what is the meaning of the "service cloud.firestore ..." (or perhaps they are out of date?)


So what is the right method to define a rule?
What I want to do is to make the "rules ..." thing work because when I tried to visit my firebase database in my angular app, I got the following error:

```
permission_denied at /employees: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data
```

All the codes come from this [post](http://www.dotnetmob.com/angular-5-tutorial/angular-5-crud-operations-with-firebase/), and the source code could be found on [git](https://github.com/DotnetMob/Angular-5-CRUD-With-Firebase).

Comment: You seem to be looking in the wrong place. The rules you are seeing are for [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).

Comment: Can you include your datastructure and the code you are using to write in your question?

Comment: @AndréKool Since there are so many details in my code in relation to using firestore in my Angular project, I just provided the link to the post from which I got the example. And the datastructure is quite simple, it is just an empty table (or collection if you want) named employees in **cloud firestore**, nothing else, there is even no document in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. By default Firebase shows you the Cloud Firestore and not the Realtime Database. Go to the firebase console --> Database and there choose the Realtime Database (is the one that your tutorial uses).

You can find it here:

[image]

In case you want to use Cloud Firestore, what you are looking for (allowing read & write permission) is:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information at [Cloud Firestore security section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) or at [Realtime Database security section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Comment: I tried this but it is also not working, same error: **permission_denied at /employees: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data**

Comment: You tried the code above or changing the Realtime Database options? The code above won't work for your tutorial because your instructor uses Realtime Database. So go to Firebase Console --> Database --> Select the Realtime Database (see the picture above) --> Go to Rules --> Change them to what your tutorial proposes to you.

Comment: I never noticed that it was realtime database, and thanks a lot for pointing it out, now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

For your firebase application you can use the following rules:

```
 {
   "rules": {
     "users": {
       "$uid": {
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Here's a link to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: This is not working, same error. **Unexpected '{'.**